# Python classes: optional argument

Tags: python, class, optional-arguments

I want the user to be able to initiate a class by passing an argument to it, and if he doesn't pass it then it should be automatically created by the class. How is that usually done in Python? Example:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, argument):

        self.argm = argument
        # logic here: if user does not pass argument
        # run some function or do something


    def create_argm(self):

        self.argm = 'some_value'



object_example = MyClass()
print(object_example.argm) # will print 'some_value'

object_example = MyClass('some_other_value')
print(object_example) # will print 'some_other_value'
```

Edit : self.argm will be a `python-docx Object` so i'm unable to do `def __init__(self, argument = Document()` or am i?

Comment: `def __init__(self, argument='some_value'):`

Comment: Since you already know how to create default arguments, this should answer your question: [Python optional parameters](//stackoverflow.com/q/1585247)

Comment: @Aran-Fey thx for the link, i'll initialise with `argument=None` and check it's value inside init. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

if you cant create the value in the function definition, you can use a value that indicates nothing, luckily python has `None` so you can do something like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, argument=None):
        if argument is None:
            self.argm = self.create_argm()
        else:
            self.argm = argument

    def create_argm(self):
        return 'some_value'
```

if `None` Doesn't fit because you want that to be a valid value for `argument` without assuming it was left out you can always create a dummy value:

```
class MyNone:
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, argument=MyNone):
        if argument is MyNone:
            self.argm = self.create_argm()
        else:
            self.argm = argument

    def create_argm(self):
        return 'some_value'
```

Comment: The usual pattern for creating objects like `MyNone` is `sentinel = object()`; creating a class is a bit overkill.

Comment: Can't we replace the `if else`(in the first case) with simple `or`. ie, `self.argm = argument or self.create_argm()`. May be I am wrong?

Comment: @abdul_niyas_pm that depends, do you know the value you're receiving will always evaluate to `True`? if yes then you can, but in general its better not to take the risk, this sort of code is in a lot of built in functions and packages and the reason is that it is reliable

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done with a default value assigned to a key word argument:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, argument='default value'):
        self.argm = argument
```

You have to pay special attention if you want this default value to be a mutable object; this may lead to unwanted behavior, as the object will be created only once, then mutated.

Comment: It is a mutable object, a `python-docx` object. I think i have an idea what you imply by unwanted behavior but i'm not sure. Thx for the answer anyway!

Comment: I added a short explanation - if you search stack overflow, you will find the long answer.